# Redirect images with mod_rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I'm trying to do a poor man's CDN by placing most of my images in another server, that is, some images are at my main server, but I want those who aren't to be retrieved from another.

I'm trying with this, but I can't see the problem:

```
RewriteCond ^.(gif|jpg|png)$ !-f  [NC] 
RewriteRule .? http://secondserver.com/images/%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

I expect these lines to redirect the failing images, but it redirects everything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rule has incorrect `RewriteCond`. Replace it by:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule \.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ http://secondserver.com/images/%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R=302]
```